# Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: JVMCFRE004 unknown bytecode; class

Tags: web-services, soap, java-8, websphere, cxf

I am migrating my application from WAS 7 to  WAS 9. In WAS 7 we were using JDK 6 and for WAS 9 we are using JDK 8.

In my application we have used SOAP Webservices and we are using Apache cxf implementation for it. For WAS 7 we were using cxf v2.7.10 (including all other required cxf Jars) which was working fine for WAS 7. But for WAS 9 we had to use cxf v3.1.11 (JDK 8 compatible).

Now the issue is when Iam trying to deploy my WAR in WAS 9, Iam getting the below mentioned Error:

00000073 XmlWebApplica Wrorg.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext refresh Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AccountService': Invocation of init                              method failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: JVMCFRE004 unknown bytecode; class=com/ao/services/jaxws_asm/StartPartyDBSetup, method=setArg0(Ljava/lang/String;)V, pc=1
Exception Details:

Location:
com/ao/services/jaxws_asm/StartPartyDBSetup.setArg0(Ljava/lang/String;)V @1: JBunimplemented

Reason:
Error exists in the bytecode.

I read few solutions that it might happen when we compile the code with different version of JDK and deploy it in different version, but that is not the case for me as Iam compiling in JDK 8 and deploying in WAS 9 that is using JDK 8 only.
Please help me in what I can do to resolve this issue. Is there anything that we need to configure in WAS 9 or we need to change in code to make the webservices compatible to cxf v3.1.11.